# React-query: mutation is returning undefined data

Tags: reactjs, react-query

Hello I am working with React-Query useMutation()

```
  const { data: createTemplateData, mutate: createTemplate } = useMutation(
mutationService.createTemplate,
{
  onSuccess: (newTemplate) => {
    return queryClient.invalidateQueries("templates");
  },
},
```

);

the function call looks like

```
 const getMutationService = () => {
  return {
    createTemplate: async (
      formData: CreateTemplateRequest,
    ): Promise<CreateTemplateResponse | undefined> => {
      try {
        const result = await templateApi.createTemplate(formData as any);
        return result;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error creating template", error);
      }
    },
  };
};
```

I am able to mutate successfully (POST API Request) however, the data | createTemplateData is returning undefined after successful network request

Comment: looks like `templateApi.createTemplate` just returns `undefined` ? You're not showing what this function is doing ... also, if you catch errors to just log them, errors will be transformed to resolved promises with an undefined value. see: https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-fa-qs#logging